# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token p in JSON at position 36

Tags: javascript, c#, json, ajax, sharepoint-2013

I´m populating webpage with sharepoint so I do a json to get data with ajax like these:

```
function completeFleet(data, target, eng) {
var items = data.d.results;
console.log(items);
var prefix = "<div class='row'>";
var sufix = "</div>";
var menu = "<div class='col-md-4'>";
var cat = "";
var spec = "";
var counter = 0;
var obj = null;
for (item in items) {
    spec = "";
    if (counter == 1) {

        menu += "</div><div class='col-md-4'>";
        counter = 0;
    }
    if (eng) {
        obj = JSON.parse(items[item].Specifications);
        for (var key in obj) {
            spec += "<div class='row'><div class='col-md-12 ftBottomSeparator'><span class=' t10'>" + key + "</span>&nbsp;<span class='t06' style='float:right;'>" + obj[key] + "</span></div></div>";
        }
        menu += "<div class='row ftContainerOut'><div class='col-md-12 ftContainer'><div class='row ftHeader'><div class='col-xs-9 t09'>" + items[item].Title + "</div><div class='col-xs-3 text-right'></div></div><div class='row'><div class='col-md-6' style='padding-top:10px'><img src='" + items[item].Imagen.Url + "' class='img-responsive img-center' style='border:0px solid blue; max-width:150px;max-height:120px;' /></div><div class='col-md-6'>" + spec + "</div></div></div></div>";
    } else {
        obj = JSON.parse(items[item].Especificaciones);
        for (var key in obj) {
            spec += "<div class='row'><div class='col-md-12 ftBottomSeparator'><span class=' t10'>" + key + "</span>&nbsp;<span class='t06'  style='float:right;'>" + obj[key] + "</span></div></div>";
        }

        menu += "<div class='row ftContainerOut'><div class='col-md-12 ftContainer'><div class='row ftHeader'><div class='col-xs-9 t09'>" + items[item].Title + "</div><div class='col-xs-3 text-right'></div></div><div class='row'><div class='col-md-6' style='padding-top:10px'><img src='" + items[item].Imagen.Url + "' class='img-responsive img-center' style='border:0px solid blue; max-width:150px;max-height:120px;' /></div><div class='col-md-6'>" + spec + "</div></div></div></div>";
    }
    counter++;
}
$(target).html("<div class='panel-body'><div class='container-fluid'>" + prefix + menu + sufix + "</div></div>");

}
```

I have 5 objects different, but one of these don´t show data, my webpage is in english and spanish, in english it charge all data, but in spanish one of these
doesn´t works and I get error at position 36, and position 36 is the item don´t show. Any idea what is wrong here? Regards

[image: Error image]

These one works
[image: Works]

and this no works

[image: noworks]

---------Update------------

If I comment this line:

```
 //obj = JSON.parse(items[item].Especificaciones);
```

and put

```
 if(items[item].Especificaciones){
 JSON.parse(items[item].Especificaciones);
   }
```

it now runs  with image, but now I don´t have my "Especificaciones" lists

Now when I use

```
var stringifyObj = JSON.stringify(items[item].Especificaciones); 
var obj = JSON.parse(stringifyObj);
```

I get something like these:

[image: Keyword]

Comment: Can you show us the content of the json?

Comment: Well you JSON has a typo in it... Look at position 36.

Comment: I upload it @meJustAndrew

Comment: Best solution with debugging steps https://daveceddia.com/unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make sure value is not null for the corresponding key inside JSON.parse. For example-

```
JSON.parse(items[item].Specifications)
```

make sure items have value in item index and items[item] has the property Specifications.

you can check if items[item].Specifications is not null before JSON.parse.

```
if(items[item].Specifications){
  JSON.parse(items[item].Specifications)
}
```

**Update**

JSON.parse() is used to convert a string containing JSON notation into a Javascript object. To be valid JSON, strings must be in double quotes.

Try stringify the object and then parse again.

```
var stringifyObj = JSON.stringify(items[item].Especificaciones); 
var obj = JSON.parse(stringifyObj);
```

The reason for the error is that JSON.parse() expects a String value and items[item].Especificaciones is an Array

Comment: How can I check if it comes null?

Comment: you can check if it is null before JSON.parse.

Comment: if I only comment line `obj = JSON.parse(items[item].Especificaciones);` it runs correctly, how can I validate it to run it? because I don´t found anything wrong

Comment: Try stringify the object. JSON.stringify(items[item].Especificaciones);  
The reason for the error is that JSON.parse() expects a String value and items[item].Especificaciones is an Array

Comment: I do it, but I only received numbers for each keyword, I upload it to question

Comment: can you past your json response as text instead of image. I want to test it.

Comment: Yes, there is now in my question

Comment: your response is not correct json string. Data in Especificaciones is not properly formatted. how did you serialized data.d.results? Properly formatted Especificaciones will look like this - '{"Bandera":"Mexicana", "Eslora":"80 pies", "Manga":"20 pies", "Calado":"5.5 pies", "Velocidad":"10 nudos", "Año":"1975", "Pasajeros":"40 pax", "Área libre en cubierta":"300 pies2", "Capacidad de carga":"6 tons" }'. Single quote in start and end.

Comment: Wooot, I found issue, that´s because a simple quote in one item -.- Thankyou for all!

Answer (score 1):

`"Eslora":100 pies"`

You should probably opening the quotes when you start writing a string value

Comment: view below. You have posted several instances, one of them is what I posted. I didn't write this down, this was copy/paste from the text that you posted.