# Parsing JSON HTTP request from Netsuite to Heroku returns error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token p"

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, heroku, suitescript

I have created a Portlet Form script that takes in parameters, submits it to the proper Suitelet and then forwards the generated JSON from Netsuite to a Node.js Heroku server for further processing.

The json that I created is fine and is returning the correct values however when it sends the request, the heroku logs are giving me the error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token p`.

The odd thing is that all this works great when I run the server locally and send through Postman. It's when I send everything through the Netsuite request that is causing problems. It could also be something with the body-parser as the error references body-parser.
I feel like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37932677/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-p-in-json-at-position-36) was on the right track but it didn't help in the end. Any ideas on how to rectify?

The Suitelet POST request that handles the JSON and request:

```
 var json = {
     "par": {
        "id":request.getParameter("custpage_id"),
         "num":request.getParameter("custpage_num")
      },
      "in": {
         "headers":temp.toString()
      }
  };

for (var i = 0; i < info.length; i++){
        var newVal = "val" + (i+1);
        json.in[newVal] = info[i];
 }
nlapiRequestURL("https://somelink.herokuapp.com/", json, {"Content-Type":"application/json"});
```

The Heroku code:

```
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, function() {
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log('port #: ', port);
});

app.post('/', function( req, res) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.headers));
        console.log(req.body);
 });
```

Full error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token p
     at parse (/app/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)
     at invokeCallback (/app/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:262:16)
     at /app/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:116:18
     at done (/app/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:251:7)
     at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/app/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:307:7)
     at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

**EDIT:** The JSON that should be printed out is below. This works through Postman but not when it is sent through Netsuite:

```
{
  "par": {
    "id": "customID",
    "num": "132"
  },
  "in": {
    "headers": "Item,Current",
    "val1": "98696,7938",
    "val2": "58839,936"   
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
After some more testing I took out the headers from `nlapiRequestURL()` and even though the info being sent is JSON, the request defaults to `"content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"`. The updated request looks like this:
`nlapiRequestURL("https://somelink.herokuapp.com/", json);`

```
The Heroku POST request code now:
    app.post('/', function( req, res) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.headers));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
});
```

This sends the JSON however the formatting is wrong. Instead of the JSON that should be shown as in my edit, I get the below:

```
{
   "par": "{id=customID,num=132}",
   "in": "{headers=Item,Current, val1=98696,7938, val2=58839,936}"
}
```

Comment: It might depend on these `request.getParameter("custpage_id")`.. what are their values?

Comment: @suraj they are string values entered by the user. The number is just a number and the id is just a string. The JSON come out perfectly though

Comment: Well what *does* the JSON look like? What do those `console.log()` calls actually print out?

Comment: They don't print out anything, that's the thing. It should print out regular JSON content as it does when I send through Postman. I'll update my question with some more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out what I needed to do was stringify the JSON object I created before I sent the data. So just doing
`nlapiRequestURL("https://somelink.herokuapp.com/", JSON.stringify(json));`
worked perfectly!